# After installed visual studio 2013 update 3, it asks me license key

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am an MSDN subscriber user, my Viusal Studio 2013 with update 2 was working perfectly. Today I installed update 3, when I restart Visual Studio, it asks me license key:

[image]

How could I get rid of this? or how can I get a new key from MSDN?

Comment: Huh? This question "directly involves tools used primarily for programming", so why closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/`  or what ever the msdn link is for your country. Click on `Subscription Access` and log into your account. You then need to go to `My Product Keys` to get your product key. It most likely is a static key that has not changed from the initial release, that is the way it is for my subscription. You may also want to read the text associated with the entry for me it states.

> Visual Studio Professional 2013
>   Static Activation Key
>
> The product key is not embedded with Visual Studio 2013. When you launch the product, you can simply sign in with the Microsoft account associated with your MSDN subscription and your IDE will automatically activate. An added benefit of signing in to Visual Studio is that your IDE settings will sync across devices, and you can connect to online developer services. If you’d rather enter a product key, then simply bypass signing in and enter the product key found here by selecting Register Product under the Help menu.

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to be of help